# How to return zero from a function with an empty parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Write a function, multiply, that takes any number of arguments and multiplies them all together. 
If there is only one number, it will return that number.
If no numbers are passed in, it will return 0.

For example:

`multiply()` returns 0

`multiply(1)` returns 1

`multiply(1, 2)` returns 2

`multiply(1, 2, 3)` returns 6

`multiply(1, 2, 3, 4)` returns 24

```js
function multiply(...a) {
  if (!a){
    return 0;
  } else if (a === Number){
    return a; 
  } else {
    return a.reduce((current, previous)=>{return previous*current});
  }
}

multiply(1,2,3);
```

Comment: I haven't played with spread operators yet so not going to post this as answer... but if you call `multiply()`, then `a` I expect to be `undefined`, therefore you should be able to simply check `if (a === undefined) return 0;`

Comment: I would expect a multiply function would return 1 when passed no arguments.

Comment: It appears if you use spread operators, `a` will always be an array. In the case of no parameters, it will simply be an empty array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After [`...` operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) You will always have an array in this case, so You just must use:
`if(!a.length){` instead of `if(!a){`;

Also, You don't need `return` in [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) callback's [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in this case. You can change it on:

```
(current, previous) => previous*current
```

Comment: I knew I was close but it I was missing such a small part thanks a lot!!!